# Jndi Mongodb Spring boot with embedded Tomcat,

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Jndi Mongodb Spring boot with embedded Tomcat,

Cannot load JDBC driver class 'mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver'. instead i already added mongodb-java-driver in dependencies ?

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource mongoResource = new ContextResource();
            mongoResource.setName("jdbc/Mongodb");
            mongoResource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            mongoResource.setProperty("driverClassName", "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
            mongoResource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/skywriter");
            mongoResource.setProperty("username", "skywriter");
            mongoResource.setProperty("password", "skywriter");
            context.getNamingResources().addResource(mongoResource);

        }

    };
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
@Primary
public DataSource mongoJNDIDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean mongodb = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    mongodb.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/Mongodb");
    mongodb.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    mongodb.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    mongodb.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (DataSource) mongodb.getObject();
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, as they can be difficult to read and are not searchable.  Add the relevant parts of your code to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JAR that holds the JDBC driver. Which vendor are you using? It's not part of the official `mongodb-java-driver`.

Comment: which JAR are used for mongodb driver ?